# Django not reusing connections to MySQL with CONN_MAX_AGE=60

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am using Django 1.9.2 in development (`DEBUG=True`) with MySQL 5.6.23. Below is my database settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': "django",
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 60,
    }
}
```

I am querying MySQL to get the number of active connections with the command below:

```
show status where `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';
```

It yield result like this

```
+-------------------+-------+
| Variable_name     | Value |
+-------------------+-------+
| Threads_connected | 10    |
+-------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Every time I make a new request to Django, the number of connected threads increase until I get `(1040, 'Too many connections')` when the number `Threads_connected=151`. Furthermore, connections are not closed after 60s.

This behavior does not seem to happen in production (`DEBUG=False`).

Comment: Is this solved ? I also hit the problem

Comment: how you lanunched Django? And Django process request in per-thread-per-request model or per-greenlet-per-request model?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are running Django in development mode, so the `CONN_MAX_AGE` is not effective because each request is served by a different thread.
From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/#caveats):

> The development server creates a new thread for each request it handles, negating the effect of persistent connections. Don’t enable them during development

About the connection not being closed after 60 seconds: [timed out connections are checked and closed when starting the next request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/#connection-management), so just make a new request to django after more than 60 seconds, it should detect the obsolete connection and close it.

Comment: At the beginning of each request, Django closes the connection if it has reached its maximum age.
Doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/databases/#connection-management

Comment: @crazysj Yes, added your link to the answer and clarified the wording a bit. Thanks.

Comment: Just ran into this with postgres & django! Using CONN_MAX_AGE > 0 in dev is a bad bad idea :-) Depending on what happens in your code, you may run (as I just did) into a situation where connections pile up in the `pg_stat_activity` and then you run into a `sorry, too many clients already` error when you have > 100 rows of `ClientRead` `idle` values... This is pretty nasty! Thanks for the great explanation!